# Undeclared Error while trying to access enum from seperate class in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, declaration

I have a simple C++ calculator with three classes (just for practice, I wouldn't actually need that many). They are `Calculator` (the main Object that uses the others) `Expression` (a simple data structure for storing to integers and an enum instance) and `Parser` (which reads in an input from the user and converts into an expression). 
Here's the code for the `Calculator` class header file:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include <Expression.h>

class Calculator
{
public:
    enum Operation {Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division, InvalidOperation};

    Calculator();
    ~Calculator();

    float calculate (const char* text);
protected:

private:
    float calculate (Operation o, float num1, float num2);
    float calculate (Expression* e);
};

#endif
```

and the Expression header file:

```
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H
#define EXPRESSION_H

#include <Calculator.h>

class Expression
{
public:
    Expression(Calculator::Operation operand, float num1, float num2);
    virtual ~Expression();

    Calculator::Operation getOperand ();
    float getNum1 ();
    float getNum2 ();
protected:

private:
    Calculator::Operation _operand;
    float _num1;
    float _num2;
};

#endif // EXPRESSION_H
```

The compiler tells me that in the constructor of the Expression class that 'Calculator' has not been declared even though I'm only trying to access the enum, not an instance of calculator (and if I were there would be no reason why it shouldn't work. If you have any idea what could have caused this problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I actually tried removing the `::Operation` part and that didn't work either so this problem isn't limited to enums.

Comment: The two .h files have circular dependency.

Comment: I have heard of this before. How would I fix it? My Operation enum is in the Calculator class

Comment: Calculator has to know about Expression and Expression has to know about Calculator. Either rewrite it to avoid this or use .cpp files

Comment: So do you mean putting the Operations in the .cpp of Calculator of in a different class or place altogether?

Comment: You only need a forward declaration of `Expression` in `Calculator.h`. Remove the inclusion of `Expression.h` and follow the guides in the dupe.

Comment: Alright! Thanks!